# Surjective continuous function $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I was in class and the lecturer only mentioned that there exists such function. I didn't find anything about it on the internet. Is it simple? Maybe you could help me to understand that?
thanks

Comment: Maybe this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: [Why does the Hilbert curve fill the whole square?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141958/why-does-the-hilbert-curve-fill-the-whole-square) discusses this in detail.