# Reference - formal characterization and analysis of Koch curve

Tags: analysis, reference-request, fractals

I am studying the Koch curve but most resources I have seen do not describe the Koch curve formally and are similar to the Wikipedia page on the subject. For example, I *have* looked at books like *Fractal Geometry* by Falconer and *Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry* and found it difficult to build formal proofs based on those constructions.

Does anyone know of a book or accessible paper that discusses the Koch curve and its properties formally?

If you could also refer me to a resource that discusses generalized Cantor sets and Cantor functions with proofs of some of the properties I would really appreciate it.

Comment: For the Koch curve, see the references I gave in my answer to [Why does the Hilbert curve fill the whole square?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141958/why-does-the-hilbert-curve-fill-the-whole-square). For Cantor functions, see the references I gave in my "question" [Bibliography for Singular Functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677927/bibliography-for-singular-functions). For Cantor sets, Sergio Eugenio Plaza's 1992 manuscript [*Numerical invariants of Cantor sets*](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/24/008/24008139.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: Also, for Cantor sets see Robert W. Vallin's recent book [**The Elements of Cantor Sets: With Applications**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1118405714). I can't believe I forgot about Vallin's book, since he and I finished our Ph.D.'s under the same person at about the same time (thus, we were in several classes and seminars together) and a few months ago I spent a lot of time writing up an Errata/Suggestions list (but I'm only a third through his book at this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigorous and self-contained treatment of self-similar sets, including both Koch snowflake and Cantor-type sets,  can be found in the excellent book *[Geometry of Sets and Measures on Euclidean spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=RTQmlDw9r6gC)* by Mattila.