# Example of a path $\gamma:[a, b] \to \Bbb R^2$ whose image is not a thin curve?

Tags: general-topology

I am beginning to learn path connectivity (in the beginning of a complex analysis course) and am trying to sort out a few issues.

We defined a path to be a **continuous** map $\gamma:[a, b] \to \Bbb R^2$.

Firstly I want to convince myself that the image of such a path **must** "look like" a curve, or in other words $\gamma([a, b])$ must always look like a traversal drawn by a pen on the plane without lifting it.

But doing a bit of googling it seems there are weird pictures that arise as images of paths and curves. One of them being the Peano Curve but understanding it requires prerequisites I do not have. So,

> Is there an example of a continuous function $\gamma:[a, b] \to \Bbb
>  R^2$ whose image is **fat** and does not look like the traversal of a
>   point on the plane, constructed using somewhat elementary methods?

Comment: The Peano curve is very much continuous. So, you may wish to rephrase your question.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: May have gotten confused. I think I read somewhere that there is no continuous map from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Is that right?

Comment: The [Koch snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) is "fat" too, and the construction is also fairly elementary.

Comment: @Ishfaaq [Space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) are continuous. In general, a [curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve) is continuous by definition.

Comment: @Ishfaaq you may have read that there is no continuous bijection $[0,1]\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: The point is that the Peano curve passes through EVERY point in the square, although the point moves continuously as the parameter moves through the interval. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: I was trying to read the Wikipedia Article on Space Filling Curves but like I said it is sadly too sophisticated for me. And if you will, why is the Koch Snowflake fat?

Comment: @Ishfaaq The intuitive concept of "fat" can be captured in mathematics by the [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension). Being "fat" is having Hausdorff dimension $>1$. In words, if you look at the construction, you can see that as the process iterates the curve gets "fatter", meaning that when you zoom in the curve is never a line, and it's infinitely detailed.

Comment: Here are some ways of constructing a space filling curve (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141958/why-does-the-hilbert-curve-fill-the-whole-square). If you know Banachs fixed point theorem (also called the contraction principle), you are good to go.