# Image of Hilbert's Space filling Curve

Tags: fractals

I am trying to find the image of $[0,1/2)$ in Hilbert's Space Filling Curve.

What I thought is $[0,1/2]\times$ $[0,1]$ \ $[1/4,1/2]\times[1/2,3/4]$.
Is my understanding correct?

The sets considered are as usual. From $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Why isn't it $[0,1/2]\times[0,1]\setminus\{(1/2,1/2)\}?$

Answer (score 1):

> What I thought is ...

From the definition of Hilbert Curve;
for each parameter $t \in I := [0,1] $ a sequence of nested intervals 
$$I \supset [a_1, b_1] \supset \dots \supset [a_n, b_n] \supset \dots $$
exists, such that each interval is obtained by splitting its predecessor into four parts of equal size.
Any such sequence of intervals can be mapped one by one to a sequence of nested 2D interval. These nested intervals will converge to a uniquely defined point $ h(t) \in Q:= [0,1]\times[0,1]$.

The point to point mapping is determined by the iteration of the curve.

- Iteration 0 :

$$[0,1] \longmapsto [0,1]\times[0,1]$$

- Iteration 1 :

$$ [0,\frac{1}{4}] \longmapsto [0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]\\  
[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}] \longmapsto  [0,\frac{1}{2}]\times[\frac{1}{2},1]\\
[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}] \longmapsto [\frac{1}{2},1]\times[0,\frac{1}{2}] \\
[\frac{3}{4},1] \longmapsto [\frac{1}{2},1]\times[\frac{1}{2},1] \\
$$

and so on. The following image shows the said iterations of the hilbert curve  [image: iteration of HC] (src [Why does the Hilbert curve fill the whole square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141958))

That answers your question.